# Как результат функции перевести дальнейшей строкой в переменную и иcпользовать ее после?

Tags: python

Необходимо после выполнения функции, в моем случае генерации строки, ее результат присвоить к переменной для дальнейшего пользования, нет идей как это сделать(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возвращайте значение, возвращенное функцией не в пустоту, а куда-то:

```
rnd_str = generate_random_string(7)
print(rnd_str)
```